# Does vuejs project can import bootstrap.min.js file?

Tags: vue.js

I have a project in vuejs which bootstrap is already installed. I am using html, css project and converting into vuejs which bootstrap classes are used. However, dropdown bootstrap classes are not working for example, the below classes are not adding Show class when its getting clicked and normal html file is showing show class.

dropdown-toggle
dropdown-menu

I have

```
"bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
"bootstrap-vue": "^2.22.0",
"@popperjs/core": "^2.11.5",
```

Can someone please suggest something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Use `show` or `shown`

The  in Bootstrap-Vue doesn't have a click event, but it does emit a show event shortly before the dropdown appears, including when it's clicked.
It immediately follows.

```html
<b-nav-item-dropdown @show="doSomething">
```

Your code:

```html
<b-nav-item-dropdown text="nav_title" @show="doSomething">
    <b-dropdown-item href="#">
        a
    </b-dropdown-item>
    <b-dropdown-item href="#">
        a
    </b-dropdown-item>
</b-nav-item-dropdown>
```

```js
methods: {
  doSomething() {
    console.log('shown');
  }
}
```

(You didn't find information for it on Vue's site because they didn't make the library.)

Comment: Yes I have done this..Just for others who may get this useful.
methods:

 callShow() {
      this.callDropdownFlag = !this.callDropdownFlag;
    }

//put this on the div where show class should show.
:class="{show: callDropdownFlag }"